# Why did the camera tech cop react in this way?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

In *The Departed* (2006), in a secret place, Frank Costello is doing business with some Chinese:

> Frank: For his own good, tell Bruce Lee and the Karate Kids... none of
>   us are carrying automatic weapons. Because here, in this country... it
>   don't add inches to your d*ck. You get a life sentence for it.

(Scene cuts to Room filled with CCTV monitors)

> Camera Tech cop: **If we had Homeland Security money like some douche
>   bags I could mention...**
>
> Queenan: Any calls?
>
> Phone tech cop: They turned off their cell phones.

Why did the camera tech cop react in this way?